# How can I get multiple values for my dictionary without them replacing each other?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
def newRecord(record):
    record= {'name' : 'test'}
    students = int(input('How many students are in your class? '))
    tests = int(input('How many tests have you given? '))
    for name in range(students):
        record ['name'] = input('Please enter students name: ')
        for test in range(tests):
            record ['test'] = input('Please enter test score: ')
    print (record)
```

For example, depending on the user input, I am trying to get record to print out as shown below and also trying to get all the values for test to be saved under the names specified.

```
{'name' : ' sam', 'test':  '99','98','78'}
{'name' : 'john', 'test':  '92','68','70'}
```

or

```
{'sam': '99','98','78'}
{'john':'92','68','70'}
```

Comment: Do you know what a list is or how to use it?

Comment: keep a list as values for each of the dictionary key items.

Comment: You are confusing `'name'` with `name`. The [introduction page of the Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/introduction.html) goes over this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a few problems here:

- Your `record` parameter is *instantly* overwritten by the method, which may lead to strangeness down the road
- You're attempting to encapsulate multiple values in a data structure which only handles key-value relationships
- You're not really taking advantage of a useful design element with Python - **class abstraction**.

My recommendations:

1. Create a class for `Student`s and have all of their information referencable in there.

   ```
   class Student(object):
       def __init__(self, name):
           self.name = name
           self.test_scores = []
   ```

   Here I'd recommend you define [a suitable `__str__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) value, but I leave this as an exercise for the reader.
2. Create a list of records somewhere which is simply a list of students.

   ```
   students = []
   ```
3. Adjust your `newRecord` method to make use of the class (and rename it to better describe its purpose).

   ```
   def create_new_records():
       students = int(input('How many students are in your class? '))
       tests = int(input('How many tests have you given? '))
       for i in range(students):
           student_name = input('Please enter students name: ')
           student = Student(student_name)
           for j in range(tests):
               student.test_scores.append(input('Please enter test score: '))
       students.append(student)
       print(student)
   ```

Comment: Thank you, I shall take your advice and rework my way to get to what you've explained above.

Answer (score 0):

use `list` as your tags imply:

```
record['test'] = []
for test in range(tests):
    score = input('Please enter test score: ')
    record['test'].append(score)
```

Comment: haha you're welcome @Milky, i bet you have a lot to learn on programming!

Answer (score 0):

You should keep a [list](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm) as values for each of the dictionary key items where keys will be student names and `list` will contain the test scores. See an example below.

```
record= {}
students = int(input('How many students are in your class? '))
tests = int(input('How many tests have you given? '))
for name in range(students):
    name = input('Please enter students name: ')
    testScores = []
    for test in range(tests):
        testScores.append(input('Please enter test score: '))
    record[name] = testScores
print (record)
```

It outputs:

```
How many students are in your class? 2
How many tests have you given? 3
Please enter students name: Alex
Please enter test score: 80
Please enter test score: 75
Please enter test score: 95
Please enter students name: Mac
Please enter test score: 90
Please enter test score: 88
Please enter test score: 79
{'Alex': ['80', '75', '95'], 'Mac': ['90', '88', '79']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep using a dictionary if you'd like:

```
def newRecord():
    record = {}
    students = int(input('How many students are in your class? '))
    for name in range(students):
        name = input('Please enter students name: ')
        test = input('Please enter test score: ')
        record[name] = test
    print(record)
```

This will log:

```
How many students are in your class? 3
Please enter students name: john
Please enter test score: 12
Please enter students name: mike
Please enter test score: 33, 45, 66
Please enter students name: otherjohn
Please enter test score: 9
{'john': '12', 'otherjohn': '9', 'mike': '33, 45, 66'}
```

Or you can do it in-place with:

```
for name in range(students):
    record[input('Please enter students name: ')] = input('Please enter test score: ')
print (record)
```

This will ask you for the test scores first though and then the name.